# Web Request by Webhooks (IFTTT task)

Tags: webhooks, ifttt

I have an Enigma2 decoder (Linux based).
It has a web interface called Openwebif where I can control the decoder.

EDIT: I disabled authentication in making things easy.

Well, if I write this URL from any browser:
http://192.168.1.10/web/vol?set=set50
It set the volume at 50 (and it returns in the browser some text of the success action). It works very well.

Now I want to do the same by Webhooks (in the IFTTT app for Android) but I don't know how to set it.
I have to set in order:

URL:

Method: (GET, POST, DELETE, ETC)

Content Type: (application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, test/plain)

Body:

Well, that's all, thank you for your help.

EDIT: I have already tried this:

URL: http://192.168.1.10/web/vol?set=set50

Method: GET

Content and body: empty.

But I get Esockettimedout error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work!
I understand that Webhooks service works only for make an external call and not local.
So I change the URL, with my Static IP assigned from my ISP (ports on router was already setted) and it worked! Of course i had to add the autenthication part to the url:

https://user:password@MyStaticIp/web/vol?set=set50

Thank you all.

Thank you Reza for EDIT, sorry for my english...

Comment: hello, I face this exact problem now.  I am not sure how to change http to https and add the auth part.  could you provide the steps that you followed please?

Comment: HTTPS you can set it from decoder plugin, OpenWebif.
The password you can set it from tellnet, search on google how to do it.